# Where are the "Connect to Server" settings stored in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, network-shares, system-preferences, plist

Where are the "Connect to Server" history and favorites stored in OS X? 
[image]

Hopefully they are in a pList file somewhere as I'd like to sync them between computers using Dropbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist in the favoriteservers dictionary.

Comment: nice. how can I import / export just that dictionary from the command line?

Comment: Read via : `defaults read com.apple.sidebarlists favoriteservers`. change `read` to `write` to write, but you have to have a dictionary to write to the plist. If you just want to add one item, you can use `defaults write com.apple.sidebarlists dict-add key, value`

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to update this as I was looking and could not find an answer that worked On OS X El Capitan (10.11.5). I started poking around and I found them in a different location.

~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteServers.sfl

1. Copy from the old location.
2. Paste to the new location.
3. Change the owner (if needed)

   - Right (CTRL) Click > Get Info > Sharing and Permissions > Unlock > select or add user (making sure it has read/write > Gear > "Make user the owner"
   - You could also use the terminal with "sudo chown 'username'
     '~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteServers.sfl' " making sure to replace 'username' with your actual username.
4. Relaunch the Finder (might not be required).

In response to the original question, you may be able to put this file in a DropBox folder and run an alias to the Library location. Not sure how it would work with multiple owners and permissions on the file as I don't use dropbox and haven't tested it.